# Как сделать коллайдер по текстуре персонажа юнити?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Существует модель персонажа, соответственно у нее при проигрывании разных анимаций двигаются руки/ноги.Для обработки столкновений с ней нужен коллайдер точно по текстуре. Каким образом можно сделать так чтобы коллайдер был точно по текстуре персонажа и двигался в соответствии с анимацией?

Comment: Текстура - это ж просто картинка. Вы имеете в виду 3д модель?

Comment: Русские "геймеры" любую поверхность колхозно называют текстурой. Как например баг "out of bounds" у нас называют "провалился под текстуры".

Comment: Да, имею ввиду модель

Answer (score 1):

используй MeshCollider

/////////////////////////////////////

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin в смысле чуть более развернутые ответы? Человек знает как применять коллайдер но не знает про существование MeshCollider. Что можно развернутее ответить?  Расписать каждое действие мышкой? Издеваешся?

Comment: ну вообще стоило написать это комментарием. но раз уж взялись за ответ, так, наверно, стоит написать его хорошо. ориентируясь, например, на топ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ты использовал юнити? Нет? Тогда давай я проведу аналогию. У тебя спрашивают "Как мне записать число с точкой? А то `Integer` не подходит" и ты пишешь ответ "Используй `Double`" а я, например, к твоему ответу придолбался и говорю "оставляй более развернутый ответ". Вот ровно это только что случилось. Этот ответ является полным и исчерпывающим.

Comment: отличный пример! вот для таких кратких «ответов» и стоит использовать комментарии. а хорошие ответы всё-таки, по-моему, должны быть несколько более развёрнуты. // и я не «придалбывался», а лишь высказал просьбу.

Comment: Комментарии существуют для всего что не является исчерпывающим ответом.

Comment: А как его заставить гнуться, если модель анимацию проигрывает?

Comment: меш(3д модель) гнется во время анимаци. Соответственно гнется и сам коллайдер т.к. коллайдер генерируется на основе меша. Если не гнется по какой-либо причине - то вероятнее всего для анимации были использованы какие-то хаки, хотя даже не знаю что там можно сделать что бы сам меш оставался на месте а модель анимировалась)

Comment: надо будет попробовать